# Which is correct has or have Neither of the balls has/have any air

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, subjects, agreement

Neither of the balls has/have any air.
Use has or have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is correct, "neither is" or "neither are"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are) Also ["Neither of us are" -vs- "Neither one of us is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470158/) and ["Neither is" or "neither are"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47999/) and ["Neither Billy nor Suzy look" vs. "neither Billy nor Suzy looks"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73765/) and many more.

Answer (score 0):

With either and neither, we should use a singular verb unless they are being used with or, in such a case, we can use either a singular verb or a plural one according to Grammar Monster (https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/either_or_plural_or_singular_verb.htm)

For example, "Either is acceptable.", "Neither of the boys is trying.", and, in your case, Neither of the balls has any air, since "has" is the singular form of "have"

Comment: For plural concord under disjunction, the disjunctive NP nearest the verb should itself be plural on its own: *Neither friends nor **Romans have** come to bury Caesar.*